# RC5 usage in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, encryption

Is there any way to use RC5 for decryption purposes in Python 3.x natively? I've only found many deprecation notices in several modules and abandoned Github repos with python 2.x code from years ago. No current module seems to support RC5 and I'd rather not implement my own crypto.

Comment: Not an answer. 

```pip install pycrypto``` Then 

```>>> from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4``` will import RC4. I expected the module to have RC5 but it doesn't

Comment: For **decryption** of old RC5 encrypted data, and given that RC5 is exceedingly simple to implement, I hereby lift the "do not implement your own crypto" requirement :) Note that you do have to have the key, the block size and number of rounds... RC5 is flexible like that.